# Do I need an input resistor for an isolated DC-DC converter?

Tags: transformer

I am using a 24V-> 12V isolated DC-DC converter and the power source are two 12V, 65Ah lead acid batteries connected in series. Do I need a input resistor at the terminals of the converter as a current limiter?

Comment: No, why would you need that?

Comment: As a precautionary measure to ensure current flowing into the converter is not too much

Comment: If you're concerned about overcurrent, use a polyfuse, not a fixed resistor.

Comment: Are you worried about inrush on the input cap or output cap of the converter? You have not even stated the capacitor size or current rating of the connverter,

Comment: Actually my main concern was that on the output side of the converter- I had already spoilt a converter which had supplied power to a motor(Ensured output current is less than the max rating provided). Thus, I still haven't found why I had spoiled it and queried the above question just to ensure myself. The converter i was using : https://www.digikey.sg/product-detail/en/cui-inc/VHK75W-Q48-S12/102-2270-ND/2162748

Answer (score 0):

You do not want an input resistor to a DC-DC converter. In fact you want to minimise any stray resistance from too thin or too long leads, it represents unneeded power loss.

A fuse is a good idea, to protect the wiring against a failure in the converter drawing an overcurrent.